# How can I easily see powdered snow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I explore, I always get stuck inside of powdered snow, a block that you will slowly sink and freeze to death in. A way that I know is right-clicking snow with an empty bucket to see if it will fill up, but that will take too long and I need a way to easily identify it by just looking at it.

Is there an easy way to see powdered snow? Or do I have to right-click every block of snow to find out?

Comment: It's worth noting that wearing leather boots can let you to stand on powder snow, which is a safer way to navigate snowy biomes

Comment: If you're willing to you can make a texture pack that highlights it in a completely different color (eg pink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

There is an easy way to identify powdered snow. Snow layers won't be on top of powdered snow when the world is first generating, but just about every snow block will have a snow layer block on top of it.

In other words, any area that doesn't have a snow layer on top of it is *most likely* powdered snow.